# Shopify Discounts GraphQL API

Tags: graphql, shopify

I have two queries, one for fetching automatic discounts and other for fetching code discounts of a shopify store.
So is there a way that I can fetch both the discounts on a single query. Also we are letting users search for their discounts by title, so is there any query that returns data based on discount title because I have seen that in products or collections inside the query we can use:

```
products(first: 10, query: "title:*searched_text*")
```

These are my queries:

```
 # for code discounts
query_1 = '''
    {
      codeDiscountNodes (first:10,query:"status:active"){
          edges {
          node {
            id
            codeDiscount {
              __typename
              ... on DiscountCodeBxgy {
              status
              title
            }
            ... on DiscountCodeBasic {
              status
              title
            }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    '''
    
    # for automatic discounts
    query_2 = '''
    {
    automaticDiscountNodes (first: 10) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          automaticDiscount {
            __typename
            ... on DiscountAutomaticBxgy {
              status
              title
            }
            ... on DiscountAutomaticBasic {
              status
              title
            }
          }
        }
      }
     }
    }
    '''
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

> ...is there a way that I can fetch both the discounts on a single query?

**Yes**, and there are two ways to do this:

First, in GraphQL you can bundle queries together into a single string like so:

```
{
  codeDiscountNodes(first:10) {
    edges {
      node { id }
    }
  }
  automaticDiscountNodes(first:10) {
    edges {
      node { id }
    }
  }
}
```

Results in:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "codeDiscountNodes": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": { "id": "gid://shopify/DiscountCodeNode/10..." }
        }
      ]
    },
    "automaticDiscountNodes": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": { "id": "gid://shopify/DiscountAutomaticNode/10..." }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Alternatively**, [the shopify API](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-graphql/2022-07/queries/discountNodes) provides a general `discountNodes` endpoint which you can use to request all your discounts together.

```
{
  discountNodes(first:10) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This approach is more efficient than combining the two queries (check out the `extensions.cost.actualQueryCost` for each of these solutions).

> ...is there any query that returns data based on discount title?

**No**, it does not appear like this API allows you to search by title. You can find the list of query filter parameters in [the documentation.](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-graphql/2022-07/queries/discountNodes#argument-discountnodes-query).